# Функция каррирования для любого количества аргументов

Tags: javascript

TODO: Напишите функцию каррирования, должна принимать функцию, а возвращать функцию
Каррирование – это трансформация функций таким образом, чтобы они принимали аргументы не как `f(a, b, c)`, а как `f(a)(b)(c)`
Должна работать для любого количества аргументов

```
export const curry = () => {};
```

Comment: Покажите свои попытки решения

Comment: Хотя и задание странное, как она должна понимать когда нужно прекращать ждать аргументы…

Comment: @AlexeyTen когда `toString()` неявно вызовется

Answer (score -1):

```
const infiniteCurry = fn => {
  const next = (...args) => {
    return x => {
      if (!x) {
        return args.reduce((acc, a) => {
          return fn.call(fn, acc, a)
        }, 0);
      }
      return next(...args, x);
    };
  };
  return next();
};

const iSum = infiniteCurry((x, y) => x + y);
console.log(iSum(1)(3)(4)(2)());
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам за помощь, ваш код действительно работает! правда к сожалению пока что не понимаю всех его этапов, но уду разбираться. Очень выурчили!

Comment: @Ian1, обрати внимание, что при передаче `0` следующие вызовы ломаются, например `console.log(iSum(0)(3)(4)(2)());`